# Why am I getting negative numbers in this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I just started learning arrays so please explain in layman's terms if you can.

At around the 50th term of the array, negative numbers start appearing, which seems nonsensical given the code. I'm running this using eclipse (latest version as of 12/19).

```
public class Array1
{
    /*
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] tree = new int[1000];
        tree[0] = 1;
        tree[1] = 2;

        int j = 0;

        for (j = 1; j<999; j++)
        {
            tree[j+1] = tree[j] + tree[j-1];
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=150; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tree[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like integer overflow.

Comment: This tag is inappropriate. The issue is almost certainly unrelated to the array data structure and wouldn't the language you're using be a better tag?

Answer (score 3):

What you are computing is the sequence of Fibonacci numbers which are know to grow exponentially. Therefore, you eventually overflow your int, which causes it to become negative.

Answer (score 3):

**Integer overflow** computing fibonacci numbers.

[Read this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

**int:** The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).